# Assessing significance / confidence of a crossvalidated performance measure

Tags: statistics, cross-validation, model-evaluations

I have a prediction model $P$ and I use some performance measure $I$ to measure $P$'s accuracy. 
The distribution of $I$ is unknown (it's a custom metric, which is somehow similar to the [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) metric).

My validation prediction is as following:

- Randomly split the data to $k$ stratified folds
- Fit $k$ models
- Estimate each model according to $I$ (which results $k$-crossvalidated values of $I$)
- The final model prediction performance is calculated by the average of $k$-crossvalidated $I$ measures.

I would like to perform some **significance testing** - to be able to say the *confidence* for the model prediction performance - to what extent I am “sure” in this $I$?

Comment: [Confidence intervals for cross-validated statistics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/confidence-intervals-for-cross-validated-statistics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use bootstrapping to estimate a confidence interval for the prediction error. Further help can be found in some [Stanford online course slides](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/asset/cv_boot.pdf), but I haven't done this.

Besides that, it should be no problem to compare the estimated performance obtained with cross-validation (mean and standard deviation) with a reference point (e.g., AUC = 0.5) or with the results of another benchmark model such as logistic regression or nearest-neighbor classifier using a simple statistical test using a given level of confidence.

A similar question is discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/confidence-intervals-for-cross-validated-statistics).